# how to create columns for rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Assume 'table A' and 'table B' in Mysql
I need to add columns in 'table B' for rows in 'tabe A'
This is what I did so far...it doesn't work

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
include "db.php";//db connection
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from table A");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$out[] = $row['columnName'];
for($i=0;$i<=count($out);$i++)
echo $out[$i];//values are printed succesfully
$sqls=mysql_query("ALTER TABLE table B ADD $out[$i] VARCHAR(255)");//values are not processed here
if (!$sqls) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

displayed error is

**Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(255)' at line 1**

Comment: Use join query http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I don't want to insert the full columns into another table I want to add rows as columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a professional but i can suggest you do one thing.

either use it

$query = "ALTER TABLE table B ADD ".$out[$i]." VARCHAR(255)";
$sqls=mysql_query($query);

or you can do it

$sqls=mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tableB ADD ".$out[$i]." VARCHAR(255)");

and everything will work fine.

Comment: white spaces in $out[$i] is a problem